# How to install geomondrian

Tags: mondrian

I have installed as described [here](http://docs.spatialytics.com/doku.php?id=en:spatialytics_olap:002_installation)

1.JRE and set the path
2.Tomacat 8
3.PostgreSQL/PostGIS

I have installed their simple_geofoodmart in postgreSQl as described
then i put geomondrian.war in  the webapps subdirectory Tomcat.
know when i went to localhost:8080/geomondrian i m redirected to the http://localhost:8080/geomondrian/index.html where  i find GeoMondrian examples:

- JPivot pivot table with simple_foodmart cube
- JPivot pivot table with simple_geofoodmart spatial cube (without   geometry properties)
- JPivot pivot table with simple_geofoodmart spatial cube
- Basic interface for ad hoc GeoMDX queries

when i click at one of them i get this error :

```
 JPivot had an error ...

 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException:  javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: com.tonbeller.wcf.utils.SoftException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: C:\Program%20Files\Apache%20Software%20Foundation\Tomcat%208.5_Tomcat\webapps\geomondrian\WEB-INF\jpivot\toolbar\htoolbar.xsl (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

what should i do ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved my problem :
1) download the jdbc driver for postgresql

2) put the jdbc driver(the jar file) in \tomcat\lib

3) Add to the classpath the path to that driver jar file (create the classpath and restart the computer if it dosen't exist)

4) change the access to the database in geomondrian.jsp located in *tomcat\webapps\geomondrian\WEB-INF\queries* , to the postgreSql database configuration :

```
<jp:mondrianQuery id="query01" jdbcDriver="org.postgresql.Driver" jdbcUrl="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/simple_geofoodmart?user=postgres&password=wakarimashta" catalogUri="/WEB-INF/queries/simple_foodmart.xml">
```

where :
**jdbcDriver** is the name of the driverClass of the jdbc driver.
**jdbcUrl** is the url for the database it have this format for postgresql: jdbc:postgresql://localhost/DATABASE?user=databaseuser&password=databasepassword.